# C# - How to get/set ListViewItem or ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem by key?

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I have a listview with several items that are created dynamically, each has two subitems that are quantity and code after a query to the database should update the quantity, but to make the code more readable I would like to access subitems by the key and not by its index, something like:

subitem["quantity"]

but I don't see how to assign the key though collections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the `Name` property of the `ListViewItem` or the `ListViewSubItem` to use the key.

From the `ListViesSubItem` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.name.aspx):

> The Name property corresponds to the key for a ListViewItem..::.ListViewSubItem in a ListViewItem..::.ListViewSubItemCollection.

The same is true for the ListViewItem.

Comment: Wow, many thanks for really fast answer, it had sought without success. Tested and OK.